# beautifulsoup select parent content not children content

Tags: jquery, html, css, beautifulsoup

I have a following html:

```
<div class="date_on_by"> 
<a sasource="qp_focused" href="/author/bill-maurer/articles">Bill Maurer</a>  
<span class="bullet">•</span> Yesterday, 9:33 AM 
<span class="bullet">•</span> 
<span class="comments">98&nbsp;Comments</span> 
</div>
```

If I use text.find_all('div',class_="date_on_by").getText() , it returns "

```
Bill Maurer • Yesterday, 9:33 AM • 98 Comments
```

But what I really want is only:

```
Yesterday, 9:33 AM
```

which is not in any children content. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out !

```
for date in text.find_all('div',class_="date_on_by"):
        dates.append(re.split(text.find_all('span',class_="bullet")[0].getText(),date.getText())[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the span class name and *next_sibling*:

```
 In [9]: h = """<div class="date_on_by">
   ...: <a sasource="qp_focused" href="/author/bill-maurer/articles">Bill Maurer</a>
   ...: <span class="bullet">•</span> Yesterday, 9:33 AM
   ...: <span class="bullet">•</span>
   ...: <span class="comments">98&nbsp;Comments</span>
   ...: </div>"""

In [10]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [11]: soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

In [12]: print(soup.select_one("div.date_on_by span.bullet").next_sibling.strip())
Yesterday, 9:33 AM
```

On a side note, if you only want the first element you should use `.find` instead of `find_all(..)[0]`.